# Помогите подробно разобрать каждую строчку(где есть //) этого кода и как называется каждая операция (Си)

Tags: c, указатели, char

```
  int main()
    {
   char s[10]="ABCDEF",*t;//
    t=s;//
    *(s+7)='G';//
    *t+=3;//
    t[1]='4';//

    printf("Text is %s\n",s);//Text is D4CDEF
    printf("Text is %s\n",t);//Text is D4CDEF


    }
```

Comment: Вы задали 10 вопросов (кол. строк не считая пустых) в одном, имейте совесть.

Comment: уже меньше.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Выделение памяти на массив из 10-ти символов с названием `s` и запись в него шести символов (остальные будут нулями), а также объявление указателя на символ с именем `t`.

```
char s[10]="ABCDEF",*t;
```

2) Указателю `t` присваивается адрес первого элемента массива `s`. Теперь они ссылаются на одну область памяти.

```
t=s;
```

3) Восьмому элементу массива (нулевой считается!) присваивается значение буквы `G`. Однако на выводе она не отобразится, т.к. после первого пустого значения (элемент массива с индексом 6) вывод строки прекратится.

```
*(s+7)='G';
```

4) Значению по адресу указателя (то есть, первому элементу массива) прибавляется 3 единицы. Из `A` получается `D`.

```
*t+=3;
```

5) Второму элементу массива ставится значение символа `4`.

```
t[1]='4';
```

---

В итоге получается строка `D4CDEF`. Так как указатель ссылается на ту же область памяти, где выделен массив, вывод у них будет одинаковый.